# Получить знак числа с плавающей точкой

Tags: php

Как получить знак числа с плавающей точкой?

```
var_dump(gmp_sign((float) "-0.5"));
```

Выводит `false`, я так понимаю применённая функция подходит только для целых чисел. Как быть с `float` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На англоязычном **so** короткий [лаконичный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556574/how-to-get-sign-of-a-number#answer-20460461) есть:

```
$sign = ($n > 0) - ($n < 0);
```

[Там же](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556574/how-to-get-sign-of-a-number#answer-32246730) еще более лаконичный вариант для **PHP 7** с использованием комбинированного оператора сравнения:

```
$sign = $i <=> 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = (float) "-0.5";
if ($x > 0) {
    //+
} elseif ($x == 0) {
    // 0
} else {
    //-
}
```

Comment: Ну это понятно. я имел ввиду какая нибудь встроенная функция есть или нет?